# JavaFX : TableView contents are not showing

Tags: java, ant, tableview, javafx, obfuscation

I have created a JavaFX application, I have built native bundle using **Ant**, and I am **obfuscating** jar with **Proguard-4.8**. 
I am able to create native bundle exe using that obfuscated jar successfully. When I run  it, it launching the application successfully, All things are working fine, but there ia one problem in TableView. That is data are present in **TableView**, but I am not able to see data in TableView. 
Below the screen shot taken from exe for TableView is attached -

[image]

**Is there any extra settings or code changes needed in class which are mapped to Tableview for data association, at the time of obfuscating.**

Comment: (i) Does it work before the obfucating/bundling operation? (ii) Have you put logs to check whether the problem is that the table is empty (no data) or the data is not shown (could be due to many factors)?

Comment: (1)Yes its working absolutely fine before obfucating/bundling operation. (2) No It's confirm that data are available. I am able to perform operation on table's data. The problem is only that data are not visible.

Comment: could it be a formatting issue (css missing for example)?

Comment: I am not adding any css for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am getting my own way
I use the long form of **PropertyValueFactory** :

```
col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Test, String>,
             ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Test, String> t) {
         // t.getValue() returns the Test instance for a particular TableView row
         return t.getValue().testProperty();
         // or
         return new SimpleStringProperty(t.getValue().getMessage());
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use "PropertyValueFactory " for the table, you should keep the Your_Object class from obfuscation. If you do not do that, the PropertyValueFactory cannot search the Your_Object after obfuscation because this object is obfuscated.

Please find the specification of the PropertyValueFactory class from Oracle at:
[PropertyValueFactory specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)

Answer (score -1):

Imaging you have already buildup so many tables in different packages then you need to change all.
No I suggest using this in you proguard_config will help

```
   -keepclassmembers public class  yourpackage1.**, yourpackage2.** ,yourpackage3.**{
    public javafx.beans.property.StringProperty *Property();
}
```